# What does ''on_packet_received()" function do in python scapy library?

Tags: python, scapy

```
from scapy.all import NetflowSession, sniff

my_session = NetflowSession()

sniff_session  = sniff(session=my_session, prn=lambda x:x.summary())

print_argument = my_session.on_packet_received('192.168.1.34')


print(print_argument)
```

i am getting this error message whenever i try to run the python's scapy script

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\unknown\Documents\coders\python_codes.py", line 7, in <module> print_argument = my_session.on_packet_received('192.168.1.1') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\unknown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\netflow.py", line 1598, in on_packet_received    pkt = self._ip_process_packet(pkt) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\unknown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sessions.py", line 129, in _ip_process_packet        if IP not in packet: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Packet_metaclass`

maybe i am implementing it wrong what does it do ?

Comment: oky i edited the post again

Comment: You aren't supposed to call that function. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if i don't call it i will get an error message that tells me i have to call it